# Capturing an incoming webforms request in an MVC route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm converting a legacy webforms app to MVC, working through it a page at a time. To make the project easier to work with I've moved all the webforms pages, which were previously in the route of the project into a /webforms subdirectory. So I need to capture any incoming requests for /page.aspx?param=123 and redirect them to /webforms/page.aspx?param=123. I thought an easy way to do this would be to setup a route handler that passed any such requests to a controller that does that job. I set up a route like so:

```
    routes.MapRoute("WebformsRedirect", "{*page}",
            new { controller = "Webforms", action = "ForwardToPage" },
            new { page = @"\S+.aspx\S*" }
        );
```

This kind of works but it doesn't capture the query string, only the page part. I can get the query string for the Request object in the controller so it's not a huge deal but it would be nice to be able to do it through the route only. My routing unit tests (which I copied from Steve Sanderson's MVC book) actually pass correctly when I test them with querystrings so I'm confused why it isn't working. Is my regular expression wrong? They aren't my strong point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QueryStrings are not part of the routing

if you requested for example `"Home/Index?foo=bar"` and you have a route that match `"Foo/Bar"` to Controller `Foo` , Action `Bar` without any more routing info (don't know anything about foo) you still can write

```
class HomeController: Controller {
  ActionResult Index(string foo) {

  }
}
```

now `foo` variable will equal `bar` , why ?
because its the model binder that gets the value of the parameters passed.

the model binder check 4 repositories by default QueryString , Routing Place Holders ,FormsCollections and Files

so what i am trying to say , the route and QueryStrings are two different things , it doesn't need to capture it

Comment: Hmm, yeah I guess you are right, thanks. I was hoping that the wildcard would just capture everything but apparently not.